# firebase function url rewrite breaking cookies

Tags: firebase, cookies, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have two cloud functions, youtubeRedirect and youtubeToken. Before doing the URL rewrite,  (as found here https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions), everything was working.

youtubeRedirect takes the user to a google auth screen, and provides a redirect to the youtubeToken function. It sets these two cookies

```
res.cookie('state', state.toString(), { maxAge: 3600000, secure: true, httpOnly: true });
res.cookie('UID', req.query.uid);
```

When the user is redirect to youtubeToken, the cookie value is checked;
`if (!req.cookies.state) {throw new Error('State cookie not set or expired.');}`

When using URL rewrites for my custom domain, it fails at this point as req.cookies is empty. When I check my cookies in Chrome, I can see the cookies have been set for my custom domain. I have rewritten both youtubeRedirect and youtubeToken in my firebase.json file

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "api",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/youtubeRedirect",
        "function": "youtubeRedirect"
      },

      {
        "source": "/youtubeToken",
        "function": "youtubeToken"
      }
    ]
  }
```

The auth side of things is working fine - authorised redirect URI's etc. all changed beforehand, where it used to redirect to us-central1-[appName].cloudfunctions.net it now redirects to my custom domain. The redirection to youtubeToken is working - my brower URL is showing my custom domain.

If I revert everything back to using the us-central1-[appName].cloudfunctions.net function address, it all works. Checking the cookies in devtools shows that the cookies are set as I expect. If I run it all with my custom domain, the cookies are also there... except the function itself cannot find them.

It seems to be that the cookies are being checked somehow before the URL rewrite has occurred, and failing? Really struggling to see a solution to this!

I thought I had found a smoking gun when having `console.log(req.get('host'))` in youtubeToken returned `us-central1-[appName].cloudfunctions.net` however placing it within youtubeRedirect has the same outcome, so that just confused me further...

Answer (score 9):

Found the answer in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62939467/cross-domain-state-cookie-issue-with-proxied-firebase-functions?rq=1)

> When using Firebase Hosting together with Cloud Functions or Cloud Run, cookies are generally stripped from incoming requests. This is necessary to allow for efficient CDN cache behavior. Only the specially-named __session cookie is permitted to pass through to the execution of your app.

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache#using_cookies)

My solution is to set the cookie like so in youtubeRedirect

```
const sessionCookie = {
  state: state.toString(),
  UID: req.query.uid
}
res.cookie('__session', JSON.stringify(sessionCookie), { maxAge: 3600000, secure: true, httpOnly: true });
```

And then retrieve it in youtubeToken

```
const sessionCookie = JSON.parse(req.cookies.__session)
if (!sessionCookie.state) {
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this and referencing the source